# Images not rendering for material ui inside Next.js route

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using material ui and next js. This is my code,

```
import { Container, Grid, Paper } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import ButtonBase from '@mui/material/ButtonBase';
import Link from 'next/link'


const Img = styled('img')({
  margin: 'auto',
  display: 'block',
  maxWidth: '100%',
  maxHeight: '100%',
});

const Home = (props) => {

  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
      "photos": {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
      },
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa",
      "photos": {
        "albumId": 2,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
      },
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "omnis laborum odio",
      "photos": {
        "albumId": 3,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
      },
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container sx={{ marginTop: '10px;' }}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {albums.map((item, key) => {
            return (
              <Grid key={key} item sm={6} xs={12}>
                <Link href={`/album/${item.id}`}>
                  <Paper sm={{ textAlign: 'center' }} sx={{ p: 2, margin: 'auto', flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item>
                        {(undefined !== item['photos'] && item['photos'].length) &&
                          <ButtonBase sx={{ width: 128, height: 128 }}>
                            <Img alt="complex" src={item['photos'][0]['thumbnailUrl']} />
                          </ButtonBase>
                        }
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Paper>
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            )
          })}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Here the link works fine but images are not loading. Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `photos` is not array but a object:

You try to get url of photo from array:

```
<Img alt="complex" src={item['photos'][0]['thumbnailUrl']} />
```

But in state you have photo an object:

```
...
"photos": {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
      },
...
```

Solution:

```
<Img alt="complex" src={item['photos']['thumbnailUrl']} />
```

OR:

```
<Img alt="complex" src={item.photos.thumbnailUrl} />
```